# Avoid New Relic attaching to leiningen on Heroku

Tags: heroku, clojure, leiningen, newrelic

I've enabled New Relic monitoring for my Clojure app running on Heroku. To avoid the overhead of nesting my app inside Leiningen's JVM process, I start up with `lein trampoline run`.

This apparently adds some overhead from New Relic attaching to the initial Leiningen process, which then shuts down and launches my app, causing delay for New Relic to attach once again. This can sometimes result in not starting up within the 30-second boot timeout window and results in downtime.

Log output showing both New Relic agents starting up:

```
heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `lein trampoline run`
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent is using Log4j
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Loading configuration file "/app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent Host: 866e2426-7a0f-4293-ae89-b55c0332253e IP: 10.159.0.212
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting audit_mode to false
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting protocol to "http"
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Configuration file is /app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: New Relic Agent v2.9.0 has started
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Java version: 1.6.0_20
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ea2dfe
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 5 INFO: JVM is shutting down
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 5 INFO: New Relic Agent has shutdown
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent is using Log4j
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Loading configuration file "/app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml"
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent Host: 866e2426-7a0f-4293-ae89-b55c0332253e IP: 10.159.0.212
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Configured to connect to New Relic at collector.newrelic.com:80
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting audit_mode to false
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Setting protocol to "http"
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Configuration file is /app/newrelic/./newrelic.yml
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: New Relic Agent v2.9.0 has started
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Java version: 1.6.0_20
app/web.1: [date] NewRelic 1 INFO: Agent class loader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ea2dfe
```

Is there a way to avoid having New Relic attach to the leiningen process?

Comment: would not using trampoline solve this problem? how much overhead is legmen adding?

Comment: It added enough overhead that I was getting pretty consistent R14 (memory quota exceeded) errors, even with much lower max-heap settings. With trampoline I can run -Xmx400m with no problems.

Comment: Hi Lyle - Did you ever resolve this? I'm working on adding NewRelic to  an Heroku-Clojure app now.

Comment: @espeed: I didn't find a particular solution to the problem (and in fact my New Relic setup has recently just stopped working, I have an open support case on that), but Heroku changed something in their Clojure setup that suddenly cut my boot times drastically with no changes on my end, so investigating the issue further was not a priority.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Heroku about New Relic reporting stopping entirely, and a New Relic support person said that they don't currently support Clojure, so it seems I'm on my own for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `-javaagent:newrelic/newrelic.jar` set in your Heroku config's JVM_OPTS, could you not set it in your production profile's `:jvm-opts` in your `project.clj`?